# onActivityResult not firing across different applications

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm using startActivityForResult / onActivityResult to communicate between two apps on Google Glass.

Calling code:

```
Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.github.barcodeeye.SCAN");
intentScan.setPackage("com.github.barcodeeye");
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
intentScan.putExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 1000L);
intentScan.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
intentScan.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Scan MQTT Config Code");

startActivityForResult(intentScan, 333);
```

Response code:

```
    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, (Intent) message.obj);
    activity.finish();
```

onActivityResult

```
    if (requestCode == 333 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        processQRCode(data);
```

I debugged through both apps, the called app gets to `setResult` and `finish`, but `onActivityResult` is never called

What can cause this?

(I'm calling a fork of the BarcodeEye project that re-enables the ability to call it through intents: https://github.com/paulpv/BarcodeEye/tree/intent)

Comment: Could you include your `onActivityResult()` code?

Comment: I can, but... it clearly has nothing to do with the issue, as it never gets called.

Comment: Well, then I'll ask it another way: is your `onResultActivity()` defined this way? `public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)`

Comment: fair. yes, and it gets called for other `startActivityForResult()` calls. In those cases, the called activity is hosted within my app, here it's a different app. That's the only real difference I can spot.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. Is there any class implementation difference? I mean, you're calling `startActivityForResult()` from an `Activity` and the other app calls a `Fragment` or something similar?

Comment: nope. Activity -> Activity.

Comment: Might this have something to do with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556206/using-startactivityforresult-across-android-applications

Comment: no. he's getting the callback, just doesn't know what format. i'm not getting a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the vast majority of similar questions about returning content across activities on SO, the issue was with my code. I was calling from inside a menu activity, and was calling `finish()` right after the `startActivityForResult()` call. Clearly, that meant no one was listening when the response came back.